# Dynamic template with dynamic scope compilation

Tags: javascript, data-binding, leaflet, vue.js

I have a very specific need that cannot realy be solved with standard data-binding.

I've got a leaflet map that I want to bind with a vue view-model.

I succeeded to display geojson features kinda bounds to my view, but I'm struggling at displaying a popup bound with vue.js

The main question is : ***"How to open a popup (possibly multiple popups at the same time) and bind it to a view property "***

For now I've come to a working solution, but this is aweful :

***map.html***

```
<div id="view-wrapper">
  <div id="map-container"></div>

  <div v-for="statement in statements" id="map-statement-popup-template-${statement.id}" style="display: none">
    <map-statement-popup v-bind:statement="statement"></map-statement-popup>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- base template for statement map popup -->
<script type="text/template" id="map-statement-popup-template">
  {{ statement.name }}
</script>
```

***map.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map = new L.Map('map-container');
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(GLOBALS.MAP.STARTCOORDINATES.lng, GLOBALS.MAP.STARTCOORDINATES.lat), GLOBALS.MAP.STARTZOOM);

  var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
  osm.addTo(map);

  //Initialize map dynamic layers
  var mapLayers = {};

  //View-model data-bindings
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#view-wrapper',
    data: {
      statements: []
    },
    methods: {
      getStatements: function() {
        return $.get('api/statements');
      },
      updateStatements: function() {
        var that = this;
        return that.getStatements().then(
          function(res) {
            that.statements = res.data;
          }
        );
      },
      refreshStatements: function() {
        mapLayers.statements.layer.clearLayers();

        if(this.statements && this.statements.length){
          var geoJsonStatements = geoJsonFromStatements(this.statements);
          mapLayers.statements.layer.addData(geoJsonStatements);
        }
      },
      handleStatementFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var popupTemplateEl = $('#map-statement-popup-template-' + feature.properties.statement.id);
        layer.bindPopup(popupTemplateEl.html());

        var statementIndex = _.findIndex(this.statements, {statement:{id: feature.properties.statement.id}});

        if(feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
          this.statements[statementIndex].layer = {
            id: L.stamp(layer)
          };
        }
      },
      openStatementPopup: function(statement) {
        if(statement.layer) {
          var featureLayer = mapLayers.statements.layer.getLayer(statement.layer.id);
          featureLayer.openPopup();
        }
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      var that = this;

      //Set dynamic map layers
      var statementsLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
        onEachFeature: this.handleStatementFeature
      });

      mapLayers.statements = {
        layer: statementsLayer
      };

      map.addLayer(mapLayers.statements.layer);

      this.updateStatements().then(this.refreshStatements);

      this.$watch('statements', this.refreshStatements);
    },
    components: {
      'map-statement-popup': {
        template: '#map-statement-popup-template',
        props: {
          statement: null
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function geoJsonFromStatementsLocations(statements){
    var geoJson = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: _.map(statements, function(statement) {
        return {
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: statement.coordinates
          },
          properties: {
            statement: statement
          }
        };
      });
    };
    return geoJson;
  }
});
```

This seems pretty aweful to me, because I have to loop over *statements* with a `v-for`, render a div for my custom element for every statement, hide it, then use it in the popup, grabbing it with a dynamic id technique.

---

I would like to do something like this :

***map.html***

```
<div id="view-wrapper">
  <div id="map-container"></div>
</div>

<!-- base template for statement map popup -->
<script type="text/template" id="map-statement-popup-template">
  {{ statement.name }}
</script>
```

***map.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  [...]

  //View-model data-bindings
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#view-wrapper',
    data: {
      statements: []
    },
    methods: {
      handleStatementFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var popupTemplateEl = $('<map-statement-popup />');
        var scope = { statement: feature.properties.statement };
        var compiledElement = this.COMPILE?(popupTemplateEl[0], scope);
        layer.bindPopup(compiledElement);
      }
    },
    components: {
      'map-statement-popup': {
        template: '#map-statement-popup-template',
        props: {
          statement: null
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function geoJsonFromStatementsLocations(statements){
    var geoJson = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: _.map(statements, function(statement) {
        return {
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: statement.coordinates
          },
          properties: {
            statement: statement
          }
        };
      });
    };
    return geoJson;
  }
});
```

... but I couldn't find a function to "COMPILE?" based on a defined scope. Basically I want to :

- Create a custom element instance
- Pass it a scope
- Compile it

EDIT : Actually, I could find $compile function. But it's often used to compile *appended* child to html. I don't want to append it THEN compile it. I'd like to compile it then let leaflet append it for me.

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue, but my hunch is that you should use a custom directive.

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to compile a custom element with a scope passed as a parameter. Read `handleStatementFeature`, it contains a few lines that I don't know how to code.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you need that functionality here. It looks like you just need to have a `selectedStatement` variable that is plugged into your component.

Comment: @RoyJ, thanks for the suggestion. that was my second idea but I need to be able to have multiple parallel instances of my custom component. That's why I instanciated it one-time-per-possible-data (statement) but I find this ugly. I'd prefer instanciate it *on demand*, thus exactly compiling it run-time from js. Just tell me if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? Instead of using a component, you create a new element to be passed to `bindPopup`, and you `new Vue` on that element, with your `data` set appropriately.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    popups: [1, 2, 3],
    message: "I'm Dad",
    statements: []
  },
  methods: {
    handleFeature: function(id) {
      const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      const theStatement = {
        name: 'Some name for ' + id
        };
      newDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('map-statement-popup-template').innerHTML;
      new Vue({
        el: newDiv,
        data: {
          statement: theStatement
        },
        parent: this
      });

      // Mock call to layer.bindPopup
      const layerEl = document.getElementById(id);
      this.bindPopup(layerEl, newDiv);
    },
    bindPopup: function(layerEl, el) {
      layerEl.appendChild(el);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="leaflet-zone">
  <div v-for="popup in [1,2,3]">
    <button @click="handleFeature('p-' + popup)">Bind</button>
    <div id="p-{{popup}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="map-statement-popup-template">
  {{ statement.name }} {{$parent.message}}
</template>
```

I *think* you could do the same thing with `$compile`, but `$compile` is poorly (really un-) documented and intended for internal use. It is useful for bringing a new DOM element under control of the current Vue in the current scope, but you had a new scope as well as a new DOM element, and as you noted, that binding is exactly what `Vue` is intended to do.

You can establish a parent chain by specifying the [`parent` option](https://vuejs.org/api/#parent) as I have updated my snippet to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Though it does not answer my question. This is probably my mistake, the code is not well focused and have trailing mistakes. I'm going to make a massive edit on my post. Basically I'm gonna forget the list stuff to focus on my need. Sorry in advance for decoupling your answer from my question.

Comment: You made my day. That works and I'm accepting it.
Though, I heard a vue **is** actually an element, and instanciating a vue is precisely like binding a scope to an element. I believe there is a cleaner way to do this (i'd like my subviews to be childs of the first one).
Although, you blew my mind and provided a working solution.